# Не работает таймер PHP + MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Возвращает "время вышло", значит r < 0, но в БД значение у "pohod" больше 0, не как не могу понять в чем дело, исправьте пожалуйста ошибки.

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
$db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
$db_table = "users"; // Имя Таблицы БД

$db = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");
mysql_select_db("game",$db);

$r=mysql_query("SELECT `pohod` FROM `users`");
list($r)=mysql_fetch_array($r);
$r=$r-time();
if($r>0)
{
  $s=$r%60;$r=(int)($r/60);
  $m=$r%60;$h=(int)($r/60);
  echo ($h<10?'0':'')."$h:".($m<10?'0':'')."$m:".($s<10?'0':'')."$s";
}
else
{
  echo "Время вышло";
}
```

Comment: Побывали выводить значение $r после строчки $r=$r-time();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
$db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
$db_table = "users"; // Имя Таблицы БД

$db = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");
mysql_select_db("game",$db);

$r=mysql_query("SELECT `pohod` FROM `users`", $db); // тут была ошибка
list($r)=mysql_fetch_array($r);
$r=$r-time();
echo $r."<br/>";
if($r>0)
{
  $s=$r%60;
  $r=(int)($r/60);
  $m=$r%60;
  $h=(int)($r/60);
  echo ($h<10?'0':'')."$h:".($m<10?'0':'')."$m:".($s<10?'0':'')."$s";
}
else
{
  echo "Время вышло";
}
```